# Model and business logic separation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 4 applications and design patterns and looked for best practices, but I'm a little bit confused, how to structure my project/where to put what code. (However, I already wrote some code, but I would like to organize it better)

I want basically the following structure: I have a backend assembly (because there runs constantly a background thread, but thats not that important), in which the lowest layer my entity model is. Then there are some classes, in which i abstract all data operations. A simple example would be, that I have an object, that provides functions to create, delete, manage rights... of users, because all of those actions are not a simple sql query, but require a little bit of extra work. Is this abstraction layer my domain model?

Then there's my ASP.NET MVC project. I read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx) about best practices in MVC projects. The second point is the one, that distracts me:

> DO put all business logic in the model.

Now I'm not sure, what to put in my model. Until now I thought, my controller is responsible for my business logic? And how are such kind of models called? Is this a view model?

Answers a very appreciated.

Comment: Umm WTf this is not at all a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought, my controller is responsible for my business logic?

No, the controllers should be as simple as possible - certainly no business logic.

> What are such models called (models with business logic)?

How about a business model.

> Is this a view model?

No, a View Model is a simple object just for your Views, they won't have any business logic.